# ¿Porque no imprime la cantidad de mayusculas de la cadena?

Tags: python, python-3.x

El programa debe devolver la cantidad de mayusculas que tiene una cadena ingresada por el usuario.

```
def eva_cadena():
    contador = 0
    cadena = input("ingrese una cadena: ")
    for i in cadena:
        if i == i.upper():
            contador += 1
    print(contador)
```

Comment: El enfoque que propones no funciona correctamente porque hay caracteres que no se pueden pasar a mayúscula (por ejemplo el espacio, el punto, etc..) y por tanto `upper()` devuelve el mismo caracter en esos casos, y tu código los estaría contando como mayúsculas.

Answer (score 1):

Porque estás usando `upper()` en lugar de `isupper()`

`upper()` convierte a mayúsculas, no es un chequeo de datos.
`isupper()` chequea si algo está en mayúsculas o no.

**Actualización:** La forma eficiente de hacer eso no es comparar la letra con otra cosa, si no chequear si la letra es simplemente mayúscula.

```
def eva_cadena():
    contador = 0
    cadena = input("ingrese una cadena: ")
    for i in cadena:
        if i.isupper(): # No hace falta convertir nada.
            contador += 1
    print(contador)
```

**Actualización 2:** Por si es más fácil de entender sin utilizar una función, esto sería similar a:

```
print(sum([i.isupper() for i in input("ingrese una cadena: ")]))
```

Comment: Claro, porque estoy convirtiendo el caracter en mayúscula para compararlos. En caso de ser iguales el caracter de la cadena está en mayúscula y aumenta el contador.

Comment: No necesitas compararlo con nada. Actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: En la última expresión, suele ser mejor usar `sum` sobre una *expresión generadora* en lugar de una lista. Además, no conviene dar por supuesto que los booleanos se suman como si fueran enteros. Una expresión más correcta sería: `sum(1 for i in cadena if i.isupper())`